# Is it possible to break sql processing after first matched condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table with records like below

```
EmpTable::
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       John    Frank
2       Tom     Hank
3       Cathy   Hoogen
4       Dorothy Fran
```

I need to find records based on various conditions. These conditions need to proceed to next condition only If the previous conditions fails to provide a result.

For instance if I do

```
select * from EmpTable where Col3='Frank' OR Col3='Fran';
```

It is going to give me both row 1 and row 4. (Same result if I apply case within the where clause).
What I want the sql to do is stop at first match, that is when Col3='Frank' is satisfied stop processing further in which case it will not return result obtained by matching Col3='Fran'. Only if first clause fails it should go and match Col3='Fran' and return matched row.

I have a very long chain of conditions to match so wanted to know if it is possible to do this in just one single query efficiently?,

I do have the alternatives that is to write a sql package and do the exist check  for first clause and break when present and return with resultset else go and run next query with different clause and so on. This package may give back 1 or more row if matched.

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one row, you can use:

```
select *
from EmpTable
where Col3 in ('Frank', 'Fran')
order by (case when col3 = 'Frank' then 1 else 2 end)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If multiple matches are allowed (or in older versions of Oracle), you can use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             rank() over (order by (case when col3 = 'Frank' then 1 else 2 end)) as seqnum
      from EmpTable e
      where col3 in ('Frank', 'Fran')
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above two queries generalize easily to multiple names.  You can also use `not exists` with `union all` for two names:

```
select e.*
from EmpTable e
where e.Col3 = 'Frank'
union all
select e.*
from EmpTable e
where e.Col3 = 'Fran' and
      not exists (select 1 from EmpTable e2 where e2.name = 'Frank');
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I am going to use the third query you provided and it works for me since I need to match conditions on multiple columns.
@Himanshu: May I please know how why my question is pointless?

Comment: @vick_4444: The first two queries work with more conditions, too. The idea is to rank the conditions in the order by clauses, so as to keep the best match only. So, just add your other conditions to the order by clauses to get them working for you. As to Himanshu Ahuja comment: I don't understand it either. You are showing that you want to allow for multiple conditions and ask how to only keep the best match, which I consider well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach where you write each condition just once, which should make this query less prone to errors and very maintainable hence. This may come at the cost of reduced speed, though :-)

The idea is the same as in Gordon's first two queries: You rank the conditions and pick the best ranked match.

```
select *
from emptable
order by case
           when Col3 = 'Frank' then 1
           when Col3 = 'Fran' then 2
           when Col3 like 'Fr%' and col2 like 'J%' then 3
           when Col2 like 'J%' then 4
           ...
         end
  nulls last
fetch first row with ties;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your SQL query is quite interesting and looks cleaner, can  you please let me know how it works? I tried running it but it complains about syntax as not ended properly. I even tried with 'NULLS LAST FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY' instead of 'WITH TIES' but that seems to throw error as well. Is this specific to newer version of Oracle? I am on 12.6.

Comment: The query fetches all rows. It orders these rows by matched condition. If the first condition is matched the row gets an order key 1, if only the second condition is matched then it gets an order key 2, etc. If no condition is matched it gets null. The `NULLS LAST` clause puts these rows last in the order. You could just as well include an else branch with a higher sort key, e.g. `else 99999`.  `NULLS LAST` is nothing new, it has been available for ages...

Comment: `FETCH FIRST ROW` (available as of Oracle 12) gets the first row in the ordered result set. `WITH TIES` fetches all rows with the same sort key. So if no row matched the first condition (sortkey = 1), but at least one matched the second condition (sortkey = 2), at least one matched the third condition (sortkey = 3), then `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` picks all rows with sortkey 2.

Comment: I don't know where your sytnax error stems from. Have you replaced my conditions with yours? Have you removed the `...`? Have you kept `end`?

Comment: Yes i have replaced those with my conditions. There is no compilation error on toad but when I run the query it complains 'ORA-00933 command not properly ended'. 

/* Formatted on 8/7/2019 1:44:18 PM (QP5 v5.269.14213.34769) */
     SELECT *
       FROM ATABLE
   ORDER BY CASE
               WHEN ACOLUMN = 'ABCD' THEN 1
               WHEN ACOLUMN = 'BCDE' AND BCOLUMN = '12345' THEN 2
            END 
   NULLS LAST FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

Comment: And If i use 'FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES'  Toad shows a warning even before I compile and run. if i hover the mouse on the warning it says: 'Found ROW: Exepecting: ( + - : CASE Connect_by_root' decimal-number........' a really long string. I tried this on ORACLE SQL Developer client as well but same behaviour.

Comment: Strange. It works here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9cdc227ea57e3d4312ce9db5c14a5b42 (That's Oracle 18 though, but that shouldn't make a difference). Please paste the exact query you have there and see if it runs.

Comment: this query runs fine on fiddle you provided. And WOW, I added few more records to test and it provides the result exactly like the way I want it to. I dont know why it isnt working on oracle 12, may this is newer feature on recent oracle versions.

Comment: No, I don't think this is about some feature only available in Oracle 18. I don't know why this fails for you. Gordon shows in his answer that you can do the same with `RANK OVER`. Look at his second query. Change the `ORDER BY` 
clause according to your needs and remove the `WHERE` clause in order to have the conditions in one place only.

Comment: this is online compiler for oracle 11. (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oracle_terminal_online.php ). Here if I run the query it is throwing the same error which I mentioned earlier.   (I have created this same table called 'emptable123' over there and it is persistent so you have just run the query to check ). I will use the Rank over for time being. Thank you so much for the sql though.

Comment: `FETCH FIRST` is not available in Oracle 11. You need at least Oracle 12 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ROWNUM=1:

```
select * from EmpTable where ROWNUM=1 AND (Col3='Frank' OR Col3='Fran');
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment Andi but this table may have many rows with same values and the query needs to return all the matched values. So rownum wont work in that case.

Comment: I am downvoting, because your approach doesn't work, as you are randomly picking a match rather than preferring 'Frank'  over 'Fran'.