# SQL query to return only the most exclusive pattern match(es) for varchar data types?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have a jdbc application that queries a database table to identify the 5 letter words possible that could be made from any given series of letters.  The application queries an existing table of 5 letter words, and returns the word (or words) possible having provided several letters.  I am seeking a sql query to return the most exclusive result possible.  As an example, suppose the following contents of Words_tbl:

|  |
| --- |
| ABOUT |
| BASIC |
| BATCH |
| BEACH |
| BLACK |
| CABIN |

Under these circumstances, were the following simple select statements run one at a time, in order:

```sql
select * from Words_tbl where word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%' and word like '%D%' and word like '%E%'
select * from Words_tbl where word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%' and word like '%D%'
select * from Words_tbl where word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%'
select * from Words_tbl where word like '%A%' and word like '%B%'
select * from Words_tbl where word like '%A%'
```

The 3rd select statement would be the first to return a result - in practice none of the words in the existing table contain ABC and D, so the first 2 statements do not return a result.  In the event a word(s) existed in the table containing the letters ABCD and E, then that result should be returned.  If not, then if a word(s) existed containing the letters ABC and D, then it should be returned, and so forth.

Since this is a jdbc application, I am trying to avoid the complexities of creating multiple connections, or achieving a result by way of multiple queries... I am striving to return the most exclusive result possible while only issuing a single query.

My best attempt to date is the following:

```sql
select top 1 *
from Words_tbl where
word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%' and word like '%D%' and word like '%E%' OR
word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%' and word like '%D%' OR
word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' and word like '%C%' OR
word like '%A%' and word like '%B%' OR
word like '%A%'
```

Modified from an example seen in this post:
[If first condition is true then stop fetching from the other conditions in where clause of a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374900/if-first-condition-is-true-then-stop-fetching-from-the-other-conditions-in-where)
A respondent does suggest the query ought to return the first row that matches any of the criteria, which it may very well do.  In an actual test in the example above, the query returns 'ABOUT' - but my desired result would be any of the words containing A, B, and C, as I am seeking the most exclusive match possible, and not the first row that matches any of the criteria.

I have also studied this post:
[Is it possible to break sql processing after first matched condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356813/is-it-possible-to-break-sql-processing-after-first-matched-condition)
and while the 'where... in...' clause and operator may be possible, by my reckoning I would have as many as 120 terms, and worry that such a query may get expensive, and complex as the given letters would vary from one iteration to the next.  I would welcome any insight as to how my objective might be accomplished.  Thanks!

Comment: What does JDBC have to do with the question here? That you are connecting using JDBC doesn't seem relevant to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Thom A, I could envision several possible ways to accomplish this with multiple queries and results, but since this application uses jdbc, I want to limit the number of connections and processing of results as much as possible.

Comment: @Thom A, your proposed solution would appear to select from specific values of 5 letter words.  Apologies if I could have been more clear, but the actual table currently has over 400 entries.  400+ terms would seem unwieldly.

Comment: *"your proposed solution would appear to select from specific values of 5 letter words. "* You would, obviously, replace the `VALUES` table constraint (aliased `V`) with your table. I don't have access to your instance, and table, so used the sample data you provided in a `VALUES` table construct.

Comment: Unless you are saying you have 400 letters to check for? What are the other letters after the initial 26? Are they things like Cyrillic?

Comment: The actual use case, is to search a table containing all previously identified, legitimate 5 letter words, for words containing varying combinations of the 26 letters in the English alphabet.  The table of words currently contains 417 entries for legitimate words (though more no doubt exist).

Comment: So why would the below not work? Is it for ties (just change `TOP *(1) WITH TIES`)? Something else?

Comment: @BobKraemer: My suggestion is that you can use the case statements and order by.

Comment: @Thom A, apologies for not having made the leap to substituting the table in for the few values previously provided.  Having substituted the query in the linked db<>fiddle testbed, the initial results are very favorable.  I think this will do exactly what I was looking for.  THANK YOU!

Comment: That could be much easier to implement if you add a column to your Words_tbl table containing the letters of the word sorted by alphabetical order and write a small UDF to return the sorted letters of the input: "select word from  Words_tbl where letters = sortletters(?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like one method would be to `CROSS JOIN` to a table (construct) with all the letters you are looking for in. Then you can use conditional aggregation to `COUNT` how many letters are in the word and return the `TOP (1)` (arbitrary) row:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) Word
FROM (VALUES('ABOUT'),
            ('BASIC'),
            ('BATCH'),
            ('BEACH'),
            ('BLACK'),
            ('CABIN'))V(Word)
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'))L(Letter)
GROUP BY V.Word
ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN V.Word LIKE '%' + L.Letter + '%' THEN 1 END) DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kp7BNv-F) with 400+ "words".